# Some hint to avoid deadlock in this pthreaded C program

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I have 1 tasker which acts like a producer and 3 CPUs which acts like consumers and a shared resources. Tasker reads a file and put into shared resource and CPUs execute and remove it. I used a ring queue for FIFO. The problem i found is CPU threads are not terminating after my tasker is finished because of the conditional variables i.e. they are still waiting for Tasker to add something for them to remove. I want shared resource to be emptied before i just kill CPU threads but they goes in deadlock. Sorry the code is a bit messy and changed because of my debuggings. I will appreciate if any of you could give me some suggestion on how to re do it. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //used for exit
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> // sleep function
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t not_full = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;  //check till not full
pthread_cond_t not_empty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; //till not empty

void *task(void *n); //function of pthread
void *cpu(void *n);  //function of pthread

typedef struct
{
    int *buffer; //;//dynamic buffer
    int head;
    int tail;
    int buffsize;
    int state;
} queue;

//globals
pthread_t tid, cid1, cid2, cid3; //id
//queue *ptr;               //our object
FILE *fwptr; //log file
int tasker;

int main()
{
    queue pt; //initialize first
    queue *ptr = &pt;
    ptr->head = 0;
    ptr->tail = 0;
    ptr->buffer = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    ptr->buffsize = 5;

    fwptr = fopen("fnew.txt", "w+"); //log

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &task, ptr);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_create(&cid1, NULL, &cpu, ptr);
    //pthread_create(&cid1, NULL, &cpu, ptr);
    pthread_create(&cid2, NULL, &cpu, ptr);
    pthread_create(&cid3, NULL, &cpu, ptr);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    tasker = 1; //tasker finished so now close when empty, noneed ot mutex bc 1 writer
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    printf("Main finish1 \n");
    //pthread_exit(&cid1);
    pthread_join(cid1, NULL);
    printf("Main finish2 \n");
    pthread_join(cid2, NULL);
    pthread_join(cid3, NULL);

    fclose(fwptr);
    return 0;
}

//TASK///////////////////
void *task(void *param)
{
    queue *ptr = (queue *)param;
    FILE *frptr = fopen("task_file", "r");
    if (frptr == NULL)
        printf("Reader File not opened");

    int burst;
    char data[15];
    // int i=0;
    int c = 1;
    while ((fscanf(frptr, "%s %d", data, &burst)) != EOF)
    {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if (((ptr->head + 1) % ptr->buffsize) == ptr->tail) //adding remainder here too
        {                                                   //check full condition
            printf("full and Writer waiting\n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&not_full, &lock);
        }

        ptr->buffer[ptr->head] = burst;              //write burst time in buffer
        ptr->head = (ptr->head + 1) % ptr->buffsize; // for ring queue

        printf("Tasker Writes data : %s   %d \n", data, burst);
        fprintf(fwptr, "Tasker is Writing : %s %d \n", data, burst);
        if (burst == 20)
            ptr->state = 1;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&not_empty);
        //sleep(0.25);
        c++;
    }
    printf("End of file");
    tasker = 1;
    fclose(frptr);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

//CPU////////////////
void *cpu(void *param)
{
    queue *ptr = (queue *)param;
    int bt, i = 0, j = 0;
    //sleep(1);
    for (;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        //printf("%s", tasker ? "true" : "false");

        if (ptr->head == ptr->tail)
        {                        //check empty condition
            if (ptr->state == 1) //if tasker finished
            {
                printf(" I quit");
                break;
            }
            printf("CPU head %d tail %d \n", ptr->head, ptr->tail);
            //printf("Tasker: %s \n",tasker?"TRUE":"FALSE" );
            printf("Tasker: %d \n", tasker);
            printf("CPU waiting \n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&not_empty, &lock);
        }
        if (ptr->head == ptr->tail)
        {                        //check empty condition
            if (ptr->state == 1) //if tasker finished
            {
                printf(" I quit");
                break;
            }
        }

        bt = ptr->buffer[ptr->tail];
        printf(" Execute blast time: %d \n", bt);

        //if ((ptr->head == ptr->tail) && (tasker == 1))
        //{ //check empty condition
        //ptr->state=1;
        //}
        // printf("CPU head %d tail %d \n",ptr->head,ptr->tail );
        fprintf(fwptr, "CPU is Writing : %d \n", bt);
        ptr->tail = (ptr->tail + 1) % ptr->buffsize;
        //printf("CPU waiting \n" );
        //if (ptr->state = 1) break;
        //printf("CPU waiting1 \n" );
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        //printf("CPU waiting2 \n" );
        pthread_cond_signal(&not_full);
        //printf("CPU waiting3 \n" );
    }
    printf("I broke \n");
    //pthread_cancel(pthread_self());
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues.

1. You should do `pthread_cond_signal()` and `pthread_cond_broadcast()`
   with mutex locked. Currently they are outside the mutex.
2. You should unlock the mutex before breaking from loop in cpu().

   ```
     if (ptr->state == 1) //if tasker finished
       {
           printf(" I quit");
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); //Unlock
           break;
       }
   ```

I think #2 is the real issue here. One of the CPU thread is exiting with mutex locked and the other thread is waiting for the mutex for ever.

**Update**
You are sharing resources across two CPU threads. Currently, for each data production, producer is broadcasting. This may cause some issue as your data consuption code is not under `if (ptr->head != ptr->tail)` In my opinion, you should do two more changes for it to work correctly.

1. In producer function (`task()`), you should not use
   `pthread_cond_broadcast()` but use `pthread_cond_signal()`. However
   at the end, i.e. when `ptr->state` is made 1, you can broadcast as
   you need to unblock all the threads.
2. In consumer function (`cpu()`), put the consumption part in `if (ptr->head
   != ptr->tail)` as below.

A

```
   if (ptr->head == ptr->tail)
    {                        //check empty condition
        if (ptr->state == 1) //if tasker finished
        {
            //unlock mutex and break
        }
        //Wait for signal
    }

    if (ptr->head == ptr->tail)
    {                        //check empty condition
        if (ptr->state == 1) //if tasker finished
        {
            //unlock mutex and break
        }
    }
    else
    {
        bt = ptr->buffer[ptr->tail];
        //Rest of the consumption code
        ...
    }
```